# eclipse how to add the windows which contains my functions

Tags: eclipse

I remove the window that show me my functions in each class that is opened now, it is on the right side on eclipse, i know i have to go `Window->Show View` but what then? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window -> Show View -> Outline